# System.ArgumentNullException: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity"

Tags: c#

I get this error System.ArgumentNullException: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity" at db.User.Remove(a),following code: how can help to fix it.Thanks

```
 NewEntities2 db = new NewEntities2();
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        var a = db.User.ToList();
        return View(a);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DeleteUser(int id)
    {
        var a = db.User.Where(x => x.User_Id == id).FirstOrDefault();`enter code here`

        return View(a);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteUser(User user)
    {
        var a = db.User.Where(x => x.User_Id == user.User_Id).FirstOrDefault();
        db.User.Remove(a);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index2");
    }



    [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            var cat1 = db.Category.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(cat1);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(Category category)
        {
            var cat1 = db.Category.Where(x => x.Id == category.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            db.Category.Remove(cat1);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var c = db.Category.ToList();

            return View(c);
        }
```

For this delete i have this view which get like model a category

```
@model WebApp.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>Category</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

       <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    } 
</div>
```

And for this method

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        var a = db.User.ToList();
        return View(a);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DeleteUser(int ids)
    {
        var a = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.User_Id==ids);

        return View(a);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteUser(User user)
    {
        var a = db.User.Where(x => x.User_Id == user.User_Id).FirstOrDefault();

            db.User.Remove(a);
            db.SaveChanges();


        return RedirectToAction("Index2");
    }
```

have this view which get user like @model

```
@model WebApp.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DeleteUser";
}

<h2>DeleteUser</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<div>
    <h4>User</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User_Id)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User_Id)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User_login)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User_login)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User_password)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User_password)
        </dd>

    </dl>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

[the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkCvc.png)

The view for the Index2

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index2";
}

<h2>Index2</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create User", "Login")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User_Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User_login)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User_password)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User_Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User_login)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User_password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete User", "DeleteUser", new {ids=item.User_Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteUser(User user)
    {
        var a = db.User.Where(x => x.User_Id == user.User_Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if(a!=null) 
        {
          db.User.Remove(a);
          db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
           //Handle 'user with id=xxx not found'
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index2");
    }
```

Because - .FirstOrDefault() can return the default value if condition not found - in class case, returns null. You cannot a user which does not exist. (Remove(null))

Same thing you need to add in your other method

EDIT:
After viewing the code - the problem is on the delete action you are returning a category instead of a user:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        //return a user, not category.

        //change this--> var cat1 = db.Category.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault(); to:
        var user = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.User_Id == id);
        return View(user);
    }
```

...
For this delete i have this view which get like model a category

```
@model WebApp.Models.Category <!--This is wrong-->
@model WebApp.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}
....
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, mate, the problem is that i have this user, and when i press on delete botton, appear the exception, i tried with another table from my project, it works fine, but here i don't understand where is the trouble. help if you can thanks a lot

Comment: it is hard to say without viewing the entire code (the view), if you look at the 'DeleteUser' request, do you see your expected value in user.User_Id ?

Comment: look mate please if you have pleasure. Here you have a link: https://github.com/todericamaxim/WebApp1 .Thanks

Comment: all relevant code should be on site and not on external sites, but I know what is the problem, see edit

Comment: ActionResult Delete is for category, you are right, but ActionResult DeleteUser is for delete user, at this code the exception appears

Comment: yes but before it gets to the DeleteUser, it goes to the ActionResult Delete, you send back category to the view, and then you are sending wrong model back to the view (cat1) instead of returning the User, this model is then being sent back to 'DeleteUser' (again with cat1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer mate, but i try to understand but i can not.Can you send a right code, how have to be, or an exemple.Thanks

Comment: look at my last edit, just change your ActionResult Delete to the code I just edited

Comment: look please in answer, i have posted my code, explain where i am wrong and how have to be

Comment: very hard to follow it, first, don't add it as answer, edit your original question. What I see: 1. Model in view should be USER not CATEGORY, 2. In the Controller, you need to Get USER and not CATEGORY - as I wrote in my answer

Answer (score 0):

the api should be [HttpDelete] not Post and it is butter to pass just Id, not whole user object

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(User user)
{
    var a = db.User.Where(x => x.User_Id == user.User_Id).FirstOrDefault();
    db.User.Remove(a);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index2");
}
```

and your problem, maybe there is chance for user in variable "a" been null, check if it is null or not

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult DeleteUser(long userId)
{
    var user = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.User_Id == userId);
    if(user is null)
    { throw new Exception("there is no user with id "+ userId); }

    db.User.Remove(user );
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index2");
}
```